# Web to Campaignmember

Tags: campaign

I want to use Campaigns in my applications, and I want my clients to be able to sign up to Campaigns via the webportal.
This means, I need to create a form and then create some code that shows all active campaigns in a picklist, and then when the client fills in the form and submits it, the form contents must be written to db, i.e. a campaignmember entry.

Is it possible to achieve this with a VF page and Apex code?

Comment: Certainly possible.  Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 1):

No VF or Apex required - just set up two hidden input fields on a web2lead form for Campaign_ID and member_status:

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000006417

Comment: Actually I don't think this would work for me, because the people that sign up for the campaigns are not leads, but contacts in my case. Is there a way of doing that with contacts as well?